# How to save open3d image without the pop-up window

Tags: python, visualization, open3d

I need to directly save an open3d geometry/viewport as a part of a python loop,
The problem is that in each run, a visualization python window pops up and interferes with running the loop.
The visualisation part of my code looks like this:

```
vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window(visible=False)
vis.add_geometry(mesh1)
vis.add_geometry(mesh2)

# Set the camera view to the isometric view
vis.get_view_control().set_zoom(1)
vis.get_view_control().set_lookat([4, 5, 3])
vis.get_view_control().set_front([-0.5, -0.5, +0.5])
vis.get_view_control().set_up([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
vis.get_view_control().set_constant_z_far(300)

# Hide the visualization window and capture a screenshot of the window
vis.poll_events()
vis.update_renderer()
vis.capture_screen_image(f'{images_folder}{iterationName}.jpg')

# Close the visualization window
vis.destroy_window()
```

I set the `visible=False` option on the `create_window` function to address this issue, which improved the outcome, but I still see (incrementally increasing) number of python window icons on my Dock. (below)

[image: python window icon appearing on the Dock]